I need to kill a process in windows but i have 2 scripts under the same process id
i've the next issue: i'm running through an url a php script, this script makes a query to mongoDb and brings a loooot of registers, this takes almost an hour to finish. To this point everything goes well, the problem is that if the user closes the navigator window, this script keeps running, which is ok, but if he opens everything again and runs that script i need to search for the previous process in windows and kill it.
Trying to do this, when i run the script i first ask for the process id using getmypid() function, and i insert it in a collection in Mongo, if everything comes to an end, i save it in that collection, but if this ,for some reason, hasn't happend yet and the end is not saved, then i search for that pid and kill it. The big problem is that the first process is running under for example de pid = 926, and the script i'm running now is under the same pid. When i kill the first one that is actually running, it kills me the actual process too.
This is part of the code:
$queryProcess = [ 'id_register' => $_SESSION['applicationId'], 'name_process' => 'validation_process' ];

    $cursorProcess = queryMongo(DBNAME, 'process', $queryProcess, ['$sort' => ['date_process' => 1]]); 
    
    $date_last = null;
    $status_last = null;
    
    foreach ($cursorProcess as $process) {
                         
        $reInitExistence = strpos($process['status_process'], 're-init');

        if($reInitExistence === 0){
            $process['status_process'] = substr($process['status_process'], 0, 7);
        }

        if ($date_last === null || $date_last <= $process['date_process']) {
            $date_last = $process['date_process'];
            $status_last = $process['status_process'];
            $pId = $process['pId'];
         }
    } 
    if ($status_last === 'init' || $status_last === 're-init') {

       killIfRunning($pId);
                              
    }

And this is the killIfRunning function:
function killIfRunning($pid) {
    $pipes = [];
    $status = proc_get_status(proc_open("tasklist /FI \"PID eq $pid\" /NH", [["pipe", "r"], ["pipe", "w"], ["pipe", "w"]], $pipes));
    if ($status !== false && $status['running'] === true) {

        exec("taskkill /F /PID $pid", $output, $returnCode);
        if ($returnCode == 0) {
            echo "Proceso con PID $pid finalizado correctamente.";
        } else {
            throw new Exception('El proceso iniciado no logró finalizarse con exito.');
        }
    }
}


Thanks in advance.

Are you running it under a webserver or directly using the PHP binary?

@Eduard i'm using Apache HTTP server

I opened the tasklist and click in "analyze waiting chain" i've 2 subprocess, "httpd.exe (PID: 4276), subprocess: 1500" and "https.exe (PID 4276), subpocess: 4532". How can i get the subprocess id?

The PID your are receiving is of the Apache server. Therefore when you try to kill it, you kill Apache with it's children (PHP scripts which Apache executed).
You can setup different approach. For example, the script you want to end can check for some signal (file, database record e.g.) and if it finds it, it will terminate itself using exit().
Is this something, you need to run from the browser? If it's periodically executed task, then Cron with PHP binary would be better for the execution.
